# Can't clone a development branch

Tags: git, github, git-clone, typerex

I would like to install [typerex](http://www.typerex.org/index.html) from its [development branch](https://github.com/OCamlPro/typerex). But I have trouble in cloning it as follows:

```
~:~$ git clone git@github.com:OCamlPro/typerex.git
Cloning into 'typerex'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (204.232.175.90)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,204.232.175.90' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Did you set up your SSH key? It seems the problem is that: **Permission denied (publickey)**

Comment: I don't know what it is about...

Comment: [Read this link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) it will help you to generate your SSH key and set it up with GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the SSH address without a valid SSH key. Try cloning the read-only address instead. It does not require any authentication of any kind.

```
git clone git://github.com/OCamlPro/typerex.git
```